# Music Playback stopped working in X due to permissions

Tags: audio

I got my Pi today and having a lot of fun with it (it's the coolest computer I've owned, and I had a lot of comupters...). I had some problems with mp3 playback though but due to my own fault.

I have installed mpg123 and I can play music ok from the command prompt without having started x I could play music by entering:

```
mpg123 <mysong>.mp3
```

However once I started x this only worked if I entered:

```
sudo mpg123 <mysong>.mp3
```

I remembered that when renaming the pi user to my user something went wrong and I simply created a new user for myself. This new user did not have the required audio group membership. Once I fixed that mp3 playback worked fine with and without x.

However I do wonder why without beeing in the group audio I could playback music from the command line without the sudo. Does anybody have any idea on this?

Best Regards,

André

Comment: Could you please post more and detail error so that we can help ?

Comment: You need to be in the audio group.

Answer (score 2):

The command is only accessible to users in the audio group:

```
stat -c %G $(which mpg123)
audio
```

You can add yourself to that group like this:

```
gpasswd -a [user] audio
```